# Expected value of random variable for two dice

Tags: probability

We have a fair four-sided dice with faces labeled 0, 1, 2, 3. We roll the dice n times; each roll is independent. Let $X_{i}$ be the face that comes up on the $i$th die

Let $ Y = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n X_{i}X_{j}$

Determine $E[Y]$

I've already determined that the $E[X_{i}] = 1.5$ and that the $Var[X_{i}] = 1.25$.
However, I'm not sure how to calculate the expected value of $E[Y]$. Could I break it up into $E[X_{i}]E[X_{j}]$? If I can, would the answer be 3.0? Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't specify that they can't, so I'm assuming that they can.

Answer (score 4):

If $i \ne j$ then independence allows you to write $E[X_i X_j] = E[X_i] E[X_j]$. If $i=j$ then $E[X_i X_j]=E[X_i^2]$. So you need to handle the terms in the double sum differently, depending on the two cases above.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$ Y = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n X_{i}X_{j}=(X_1+ \dots+ X_n)^2$$

Comment: Thank you. So the answer would be 3.5?

Comment: The answer will depend on n